# how to position functions inside an ajaxvalidation function

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

how to position window alert and two functions

functions: "saveEdit" and set "setInterval"

in my ajax validation engine?

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // SUCCESS AJAX CALL, replace "success: false," by:     success : function() { callSuccessFunction() }, 
        $("#form1").validationEngine({
            ajaxSubmit: true,
                ajaxSubmitFile: "note/note.php",

                window.alert("Report Sent!");
                function saveEdits() {//write a confirmation to the user
                document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Report Sent!";

                setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="";},3000);
                }

        })
    });
    </script>
```

i don't know hot to position it correctly, it always set the validation engine in error when i try to put it inside.

Comment: I think you're referring to this plugin?  http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/using-form-ajax-validation-with-the-jquery-validation-engine-plugin/.  Are you trying to call `saveEdits` after successful validation?  What is the purpose of the `setInterval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using [this plugin](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine), but the options seem to differ, so maybe you are using an old version of this.

Anyhow, you are passing an object to the `validationEngine`-function, but you are breaking the syntax by simply putting a function-definition, an alert-call and so on into it.

The "success"-function, that is mentioned in the code-comment, must be defined as property of the object you are passing to the function as parameter.

So, this should probably look more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // SUCCESS AJAX CALL, replace "success: false," by:     success : function() { callSuccessFunction() }, 
        $("#form1").validationEngine({
            ajaxSubmit: true,
            ajaxSubmitFile: "note/note.php",
            success: function(){
                window.alert("Report Sent!");

                //write a confirmation to the user
                document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Report Sent!";

                setTimeout(function(){
                   document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="";
                },3000);

            }
        });
});
```

The `success` - property carries an anonymous-function, that will be executed by the plugin as "callback" - function, after the validation was successful.

And I changed your `setInterval` to a `setTimeout` as I think there won't be a reason to clear the content of an already empty element all 3 seconds again.

As stated above, the property-names aren't the right ones for the plugin I linked, if that's the one you are actually using. If so, check the [documentation](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/), but the main problem in your script is the faulty object syntax.